# Problem in installing mclust package on R in UBUNTU 16.04 - /bin/bash: f95: command not found

Tags: 16.04, r

I tried to install R `mclust` package in Ubuntu 16.04 by this:

```
install.packages("mclust")
```

But I got this error.

```
    Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.um.ac.ir/src/contrib/mclust_5.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2749972 bytes (2.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mclust’ ...
** package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
f95   -fpic  -g -O2  -c mclust.f -o mclust.o
/bin/bash: f95: command not found
/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:155: recipe for target 'mclust.o' failed
make: *** [mclust.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/mclust’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpd4PnFn/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("mclust") :
installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Can you give us the result of `which bash`?

Comment: @don.joey The result is `/bin/bash`

Comment: And `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @don.joey The result is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: and `which f95`?

Comment: @don.joey No result for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with the fortran compiler (`/bin/bash: f95: command not found`): you have not installed it. You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

Comment: Thank you @don.joey! the problem was exactly this! :) You saved me!

Comment: You're welcome. happy clustering!